# R CMD BATCH Choose version of R that is not default

Tags: r, batch-file, cmd

I need to run a job on a cluster using a version of R that is not the default.  Usually I use,

```
R CMD BATCH myfile.R myfileout
```

but this uses the default version of R.  I have the file path for the different version of R that I need to use that is already on the cluster that is something like:

```
/file/path/R-x.y.z/
```

How can I run this job using a different version of R?

Comment: Just specify the path to the executable, e.g. `/file/path/R-x.y.z/bin/R CMD BATCH myfile.R myfileout` ... ?

Answer (score 7):

Just specify the path to the executable, e.g.

```
/file/path/R-x.y.z/bin/R CMD BATCH myfile.R myfileout
```

? (You'll need to check the actual location of the R executable ... I *think* it's typically within the `bin` directory in the R-x.y.z directory but haven't checked)

Comment: Thank you.  It was in the bin directory for me.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer didn't work on my university's cluster system, it kept using the newest installed version, even when I was using the full path to the older version.

I was still able to get a script to run (on the command line, at least) by instead running something like this:

```
/share/apps/R-2.11.0/bin/R --vanilla "--args 1 2 3 herewego" < test.R > test.Rout
```

Its now using the old version for me (2.11.0), not the new one (3.1.2 I think).

Hope this helps someone who has the same problem :-)